# Covariance matrix of errors for homoskedasticity/heteroskedasticity

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, heteroscedasticity, error

I've seen homoskedasticty and heteroskedasticity defined as the following

- The error term of our regression model is homoskedastic if the variance of the conditional distribution of $u_{i}$ given $X_{i}, \operatorname{Var}\left(u_{i} \mid X_{i}=x\right)$, is constant for all observations in our sample:
  $$
  \operatorname{Var}\left(u_{i} \mid X_{i}=x\right)=\sigma^{2} \forall i=1, \ldots, n .
  $$
- If instead there is dependence of the conditional variance of $u_{i}$ on $X_{i}$, the error term is said to be heteroskedastic. We then write
  $$
  \operatorname{Var}\left(u_{i} \mid X_{i}=x\right)=\sigma_{i}^{2} \forall i=1, \ldots, n
  $$
- Homoskedasticity is a special case of heteroskedasticity.

$$(\text {  } {u}_{i} \text { is the error term. },X_{i} \text { is the independent variable) }$$

https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/5-4-hah.html

So I am curious if we take it to multiple independent variables, how the  covariance matrix of the errors look.

**This is my understanding**:

So if we have an error vector $\boldsymbol{u}$,

homoskedastic and uncorrelated errors : covariance matrix is a diagonal matrix $\sigma^2 \boldsymbol{I}$, where the diagonal elements  are all the same value $\sigma^2$

homoskedastic and correlated errors : covariance matrix is  a nondiagonal matrix where the diagonal elements are all the same value $\sigma^2$.

heteroskedastic and uncorrelated errors: covariance matrix is is a diagonal matrix where the diagonal elements are not all  the same value

heteroskedastic and correlated errors: covariance matrix is is a nondiagonal matrix where the diagonal elements are not all the same value.

Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if what I wrote after "This is my understanding:" is correct.

Comment: Your question is not a good fit on this site, because "there is no actual problem to be solved."  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: my understanding of that rule is its regarding subjective questions: as it says "avoid asking subjective questions where …" . The example given  for no actual problems is "“I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”, where as this is an objective question. But if you think it goes against the rules, I will delete the question.